# /var/mapr/cluster/yarn/rm/staging/username/.staging/job_id_1234_4321/libjars/myudfs.jar (Invalid argument)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, staging, mapr

We are using Mapr with PAM Authentication to execute select query on hive. Select query uses a myudfs.jar where we have defined our UDFs.

I have tried many links but couldn't figure out why this is happening. From the stacktrace it seems like Hadoop is not able to copy the jar into libjars directory inside /.staging. But UDF is there in the classpath.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. 2063.142.526190 /var/mapr/cluster/yarn/rm/staging/username/.staging/job_112233333_0002/libjars/myudfs.jar (Invalid argument)

at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380)

at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:257)

at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91)

at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:348)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1669)

at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:362)

at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.io.IOException: 2063.142.526190 /var/mapr/cluster/yarn/rm/staging/username/.staging/job_112233333_0002/libjars/myudfs.jar (Invalid argument)

at com.mapr.fs.Inode.throwIfFailed(Inode.java:390)

at com.mapr.fs.Inode.flushPages(Inode.java:505)

at com.mapr.fs.Inode.releaseDirty(Inode.java:583)

at com.mapr.fs.MapRFsOutStream.dropCurrentPage(MapRFsOutStream.java:73)

at com.mapr.fs.MapRFsOutStream.write(MapRFsOutStream.java:85)

at com.mapr.fs.MapRFsDataOutputStream.write(MapRFsDataOutputStream.java:39)

at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:87)

at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:59)

at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:119)

at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:376)

at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:346)

at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:297)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.copyRemoteFiles(JobResourceUploader.java:203)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadFiles(JobResourceUploader.java:128)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:98)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:193)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1669)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:575)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:570)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1669)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:570)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:561)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:414)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:151)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:201)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:79)



at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:283)
```

Following is the process how we execute the query and what we do before executing it.

First we create a function as given below
CREATE FUNCTION func_name AS 'com.test.ClassContainingMapper'

This ClassContainingMapper class is packed in a udf jar named myudf.jar. We have this jar added in the classpath by using property hive.aux.jars.path.

Now, our query is as follows:
Select func_name(col1, col2) from dbname.tablename;

When this query is executed Hadoop tries to upload the jars mentioned in the classpath to it's libjars folder under staging directory. That's when it fails.

Interesting thing is that on one similar cluster this query executes successfully but on other cluster it is being failed with the exception mentioned in the stacktrace.

UPDATE:

Actually there is another query executed before the Select query. It's

ADD JAR '/path/to/the/jar/file/myudf.jar';

This makes more sense that when this query is executed then the jar is uploaded to the cluster. And during that action of uploading query fails.

Comment: Could you provide more information about query you are trying to run and how is JAR parameter passed to query?

Comment: Hi,
Ok let me edit this question

Comment: I have updated the question. Please let me know if you need more information. I am desperately looking for an answer. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks